# Google Analytics - see where users came from

Tags: google-analytics

I have two websites with separate google analytics code.  I'm curious to know how people get to a specific page in Site A.  In GA, if I go to the site content, find the page and then add a secondary parameter for the referer, I can see google, direct, plus some other domains.

How do I see which of my pages people are coming from to view a specific page?

Comment: In the content reports select a page and then click on the tab "navigation summary" (at the top left of the graph). I don't think this is really on-topic, though.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  Site B is a subdomain of Site A.  Is it possible to find how many times a person got to a page on Site A from Site B?  They are separate google analytics sites but I'm not seeing it as a referrer in my reports - I'm guessing because it has the same domain.

Comment: I see we have a referral exclusion for that domain to prevent tracking people twice between sites.  That's likely why it does not appear as a referral.